# What is wrong with this hair particle system?

Tags: particles, hair

I'm trying to make a character with long hair and for some reason the hair is not smooth, there are no subdivisions and your can see every vertex. Also when I go into particle edit, there are random vertex's just floating around. Does anyone know what's going on here?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2):

To make the hair smoother, increase the path steps.

To prevent the keypoints from floating everywhere, rekey it to a higher number.

[image]

[image]

**Update**

Based on your comment, I do not understand what you are asking. There is no project file available to check. So, here is what I guess.
I guess you are asking about how to make smooth children hairs shown on the viewport.
[image]

To make the children hairs smooth, in the Object mode, increase the Strand Steps under the Viewport Display on the Particle tab, as shown on the following screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, that does make the paths smoother, but the hair itself is still jagged. This is strange because I have made hair particles with jagged paths and the hair itself remained smooth.

Comment: @TheMadMothra The answer is updated.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, This got me kind of exhausted so I took a break from blender. I tried increasing the steps and rekeying, and the hair moved a little bit but it is still jagged.